# putting sql query in function php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to put an SQL query in a PHP function but am getting the following error in the terminal

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /Users/file.php on line 18
```

Please see line 16 to 22 of my PHP code below:

```
function testFunction() {
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM testNumber WHERE test = '1'"
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
     return $result->num_rows;
}

$testVariable = $testFunction();
echo $testVariable;
```

Comment: pass $conn to function

Comment: Just pass the object $conn in your function through parameters, or in global (ugly)

Comment: SCOPE, Scope oh and **scope** [See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Oh and it is far more efficient to do a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testNumber WHERE test = '1'` than getting MYSQL to generate a result set you are not going to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$conn` is not accessible in the function **scope**,

You need somehow to access the `$conn` variabel to use it.

You have two options, Pass the `$conn` as function argument.

`function myFunc($conn)`

or use the **global** keyword. ([See reference for Variables Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php))

**Passing Connection:**

```
   function testFunction($conn) {
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM testNumber WHERE test = '1'"
         $result = $conn->query($sql);
         return $result->num_rows;
    }

    $conn = new mysqli(,,,);
    $testVariable = testFunction($conn);
    echo $testVariable
```

**Using global:**

```
function testFunction() {
     global $conn;
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM testNumber WHERE test = '1'"
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
     return $result->num_rows;
}

$testVariable = testFunction();
echo $testVariable
```

Comment: Using global variables is generally discouraged, so the first method is definitely preferrable.